# What are the differences between Java and Kotlin inner/local/anonymous classes?

Tags: java, kotlin

What are the name equivalents and main differences between Java and Kotlin nested/inner/local classes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are the name equivalents:

```
| Kotlin            | Java                                      |
|-------------------|-------------------------------------------|
| Inner Classes     | Non-Static Nested Classes / Inner Classes |
| Nested Classes    | Static Nested Classes                     |
| Local Classes     | Local Classes                             |
| Anonymous Objects | Anonymous Classes                         |
```

This is a quick overview of differences:

- In both cases, we can group multiple classes in the same file. However, in [Kotlin we can have multiple top-level classes in the same .kt file](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#source-file-names), [in Java we can have many classes per compilation unit but only one can be public](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6).
- Kotlin anonymous objects have support to implement multiple interfaces.
- Java anonymous classes are limited to implement only one abstract class or interface.
- In Kotlin we can mutate a local variable from a [closure](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#closures); because of that the Java concept of effectively final doesn't apply to Kotlin.
- In Kotlin inner classes to reference the instance of the outer class, we need to use the [qualifier this expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html#qualified).

  Some examples can be found over on [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-inner-classes).

Comment: Java is actually the language that introduced the term ["inner class"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) and it has exactly the same meaning as in Kotlin. So there's no need to describe it in a roundabout way.